# Error invalid binary from itunes connect?

Tags: xcode, binary, app-store

I have submitter my universal application .app file to iTunes connect and it shows 'Invalid Binary' status and i got a mail from apple. The mail content is

```
"Invalid Binary Architecture - iOS 3.0 introduced support for multiple binary architectures. If your binary is built for multiple architectures, your Info.plist must have a MinimumOSVersion key with a value of at least 3.0. Additionally, if your app is intended to support earlier iPhone and iPod touch models, your app must contain at least an armv6 binary; "thin" armv7-only binaries will not be accepted unless the armv7 required device capability is also present in the Info.plist UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key or the MinimumOSVersion key has a value of 4.3 or higher.".
```

This is first time for me to submitting app to app store. How help me to solve this problem? What can i to do this? I can't understand the actual meaning of the mail content. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either add armv6 to your Target Build Settings Architectures, or set the minimum OS Deployment Target to 4.3

Answer (score 1):

In your Xcode project, what architectures and iOS version are you building for?  It sounds like you have the supported iOS setting set to 3.x, but the architecture set to armv7.

The simplest way to fix this, I'm imagining, is to set the supported SDK to something later than 4.x.  I target 4.2, which seems to be generally safe.

Comment: Thanks for your spot response. My Xcode version is 4.2 and i have set a target ios 4.0 and the base sdk is ios 5.0. What is the exact mean for "Info.plist must have a MinimumOSVersion key with a value of at least 3.0. Additionally, if your app is intended to support earlier iPhone and iPod touch models, your app must contain at least an armv6 binary; "thin" armv7-only binaries will not be accepted unless the armv7 required device capability is also present in the Info.plist UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key or the MinimumOSVersion key has a value of 4.3 or higher." Please help me to solve this.

Comment: The MinimumOSVersionKey is exactly what it sounds like.  Every XCode project contains a file called Info.plist that contains metadata describing the app.  You need to edit this and add that key, with a value of 4.0.

If you go to the project properties, you can right click and select "show actual key names" from the context menu to get it to show the actual key names.  You then add a key, give it that name, and the appropriate value.

Comment: Thanks. I can not find MinimumOSVersionKey in info.plist. But, i found the Required device capabilities in info.plist. What i should do in this? Sorry for the disturbance. Please help me. Today i need to submit the app to app store. Thanks.

Comment: I have checked my project settings. It shows Standard (armv7) in architecture. What should i do?

Comment: You have to add the key to info.plist.  Put the project properties into the "show actual key names" mode, and click on the little + sign at the bottom of the list.  Edit the name of the new key, and set it to "MinimumOSVersion" and set the value to 4.0.