# invalid binary error in iTunes connect after version upgrade

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, app-store

I am trying to upload a further version 1.1 to appstore. Whenever I submit the application successfully,it shows waiting for review and after a while it again show Invalid binary in iTunes connect.

I have followed various article of stackoverflow and others but it is still same as it was.

- Followed this link

  [Error invalid binary from itunes connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096336/error-invalid-binary-from-itunes-connect)

  [invalid binary error in iTunes connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765443/invalid-binary-error-in-itunes-connect)

  [What can cause "invalid binary" with no email followup from iTunes Connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433360/what-can-cause-invalid-binary-with-no-email-followup-from-itunes-connect)

I have revoked all certificates and provissioning and created new one.

I have checked all icon images.

I have increased bundle version as like 1.1.1 also.

but still same problem is here.

Comment: did you found a fix for this?

Comment: Yes i have found it. This was my side problem to upload build to app store from itunes account . I was disabling advertisement but it was enabled in my app so it was automatically rejected by apple and showing error.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check in my app to see if I'm doing something similar. Thanks again